# iPod touch 4 vs iPhone 4 performance

Tags: iphone, ipod-touch

I'm working on a game for iOS platform. It's running smooth on 60 FPS on iPhone 4 iOS 4.3, iPad iOS 4.3, iPad2 ios 4.3, but it gives only 30-34 FPS on iPod touch 4 with iOS 5.As i know the hardware on iPhone 4 and iPod touch 4 is the same except RAM (512 iphone, 256 ipod). Is it a normal behavior and if not where can be the problem? Thanks

**Some additional info:**

the game is using openGL ES 2.0

it's a 2D game and if i remove background layers from rendering ipod can run at 60 FPS. So i think the problem is related to GPU but I have no idea how to fix it.

Comment: We've seen better performance on the IPhone too while testing one of our games, but both the IPhone and IPod Touch were running iOS 4 back then. This is definitely something I would expect to happen based on my own experience, but just in case I would try to test it on an IPhone 4 running iOS5.

Comment: @EliBud: Did the difference was about a half? (60 FPS vs 30)

Comment: I don't remember exactly because it was good enough for what we needed, but I think it was more like between 20-30% less FPS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tried on the other ipod 4 32 GB running iOS 4.2.1. No problems were detected. Strange